# Deactivate Snapping for Measure Maptool (mActionMeasure) in QGIS temporarily

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, snapping, measurements

I use the QGIS measure-tool to measure distances. I often would like to deactivate the snapping temporarily while using the measure-tool.

Is it possible to deactivate snapping (for example with a shortcut) while measuring and re-activating is when i digitize again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could create a function whereby:

- If the mActionMeasure button is checked, the snapping mode is turned `Off`
- If the mActionMeasure button is unchecked, the snapping mode is turned `On`

Here is the function which you can paste into the **Python Console** (change the parameters to fit your needs, you don't need to change the lines which include `proj.setSnapSettingsForLayer(...)`):

```
def snap_func():
    proj = QgsProject.instance()
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    if iface.actionMeasure().isChecked():
        proj.writeEntry('Digitizing', 'DefaultSnapType', 'off') 
        proj.setSnapSettingsForLayer(layer.id(), True, 0, 0, 0, True)
    else:
        proj.writeEntry('Digitizing', 'DefaultSnapType', 'to vertex and segment') 
        proj.writeEntry('Digitizing', 'SnappingMode', 'current_layer') 
        proj.writeEntry('Digitizing','DefaultSnapTolerance', 10.0)
        proj.setSnapSettingsForLayer(layer.id(), True, 0, 0, 0, True)
```

Then type the following to connect the mActionMeasure button to the function:

```
iface.actionMeasure().toggled.connect(snap_func)
```

---

**Edit:**

- To save and restore snapping settings for `Current` and `All visible layers`:

  ```
  proj = QgsProject.instance()
  # Create dictionary
  snap_options_dict = {}
  def snap_func():
      layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()  
      if iface.actionMeasure().isChecked():
          # Save current snapping settings        
          snap_options_dict['SnappingMode'] = proj.readEntry('Digitizing','SnappingMode')[0]
          snap_options_dict['DefaultSnapType'] = proj.readEntry('Digitizing','DefaultSnapType')[0]
          snap_options_dict['DefaultSnapTolerance'] = proj.readEntry('Digitizing','DefaultSnapTolerance')[0]
          # Switch snapping off
          proj.writeEntry('Digitizing', 'DefaultSnapType', 'off') 
          proj.writeEntry('Digitizing', 'DefaultSnapTolerance', 0.0) 
          proj.setSnapSettingsForLayer(layer.id(), True, 0, 0, 0, True)
      else:
          # Load snapping settings saved in dictionary
          proj.writeEntry('Digitizing', 'SnappingMode', snap_options_dict['SnappingMode']) 
          proj.writeEntry('Digitizing', 'DefaultSnapType', snap_options_dict['DefaultSnapType'])
          proj.writeEntry('Digitizing','DefaultSnapTolerance', snap_options_dict['DefaultSnapTolerance'])
          proj.setSnapSettingsForLayer(layer.id(), True, 0, 0, 0, True)

  iface.actionMeasure().toggled.connect(snap_func)
  ```
- To save and restore snapping settings for `Advanced`:

  ```
  proj = QgsProject.instance()
  # Create dictionary
  snap_options_dict = {}
  def snap_func():
      if iface.actionMeasure().isChecked():
          for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
              # Save current snapping settings        
              snap_options_dict[layer.id()] = proj.snapSettingsForLayer(layer.id())
              # Switch snapping off
              proj.setSnapSettingsForLayer(layer.id(), False, 0, 0, 0, False)
      else:
          for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
              # Load snapping settings saved in dictionary
              proj.setSnapSettingsForLayer(layer.id(), \
              snap_options_dict[layer.id()][1], \
              snap_options_dict[layer.id()][2], \
              snap_options_dict[layer.id()][3], \
              snap_options_dict[layer.id()][4], \
              snap_options_dict[layer.id()][5])

  iface.actionMeasure().toggled.connect(snap_func)
  ```

Comment: This looks good. Is it also possible to save the current snapping settings and restore them? I use advanced snapping settings with different settings for several layers? So the best option would be saving the current snapping settings and restore them after deactivating the measure-tool. Is this possible, too?

Comment: @markgraeflerland - Edited my post (again) to show two methods for saving and restoring snapping settings depending on `Layer selection` :)

Comment: Great solution. works as expected

Comment: @markgraeflerland - Glad it worked :)